# change monodevelop f# file order

Tags: f#, monodevelop

I have started using MonoDevelop for F# on a Mac. It's pretty cool, except for the fact that it crashes quite a lot. One thing that is bothering me is that I can't change the order of the F# source files in a project. Is this possible? It will make organising projects a bit of a nightmare if it isn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can reorder files. There is a special tab for doing that in project options (under the build tab).

Unfortunatelly, this cannot be done using the file browser (because MonoDevelop automatically sorts files by file name and there is no way to disable it).

Comment: Wow, they hid that one away! Thanks for that. LOVE your book by the way.

Comment: BTW, if anyone wants to do this in the filebrowser, now would be the time to submit patches to MD core before MD 2.6 gets locked down for release :)

Comment: "because MonoDevelop automatically sorts files by file name and there is no way to disable it" This is no longer true, but moving the file doesn't help. "There is a special tab for doing that in project options (under the build tab)." I have no idea what you are referring to.

Comment: It might be changed now (in 2016), I can change the order directly in the monodevelop 5.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using MonoDevelop 4.x and a recent version of F# Binding, you can drag and drop to move files into a correct order (no shortcut key supported yet).

Here is [the original issue](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/issues/135) and [the pull request](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/pull/228) if you're interested in (big thanks to Dave Thomas for implementing this).

As a last resort, you can open `fsproj` files in a text editor and rearrange xml nodes corresponding to source files.